# WebkitView content height overflowing

Tags: javascript, ios, css, swift, wkwebview

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NhHz.png)

This is the view of my webview content of which bottom is overflowing and is not visible. What I figured out is the parent view of webview is covering entire screen and the child view is covering entire screen leaving app status bar area. But both of them is having equal dimensions, and this is why my child view is overflowing downward.

I read many solution and most of them I tried but no difference is found.

html file that I am loading

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, heigth=device-height, width=device-width">
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
  <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>XYZ</title>
  <base href=".">

  <!-- <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <root id="app-root"></root>
<script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="styles.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

webkit view

```
static func getWebKitView(uiController : ViewController, handlerName : String) -> WKWebView {
        let  controller = WKUserContentController()
        controller.add(uiController as! WKScriptMessageHandler, name: handlerName)

        let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        config.userContentController = controller

        let webKitView = WKWebView(frame: .init(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: DeviceInfo().getDeviceBounds().w, height: DeviceInfo().getDeviceBounds().h-2), configuration: config)
            webKitView.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
            webKitView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
//            webKitView.frame.size = webKitView.scrollView.contentSize
        webKitView.scrollView.contentSize = webKitView.frame.size
            webKitView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
        return webKitView
    }
```

How can I correct this UI issue

Comment: set constraints for your WebkitView and below that place other desired elements of choice and it shall work fine

Comment: web view is within the screen. it is the content of webview that is not showing properly

Comment: are you talking about try later Button

Comment: yes that button present in the ui which is displayed by webview

Answer (score 0):

Give the Height for Web Kit View 100 points less than the device bounds

and then give y position to your Child view as  heightOfYourWebView + 10 so the Button will be below the WebkitView and above the bottom of the screen also give width as 350 and height for button as 30 and the view will not go out of bounds